# Drupal fetching object

Tags: hooks

I am trying to fetch an object:

```
$field_name= 'field_test';
$json_code = $node->$field_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

NOT WORKING

```
$json_code = $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
```

WORKING

I must have variable because it's every time different field name

any solution?

Comment: `$var = $node->$field_name; $json = $var['und'][0]['value'];`

Comment: Thx that worked!!

Answer (score 5):

Your PHP is incorrect for what you're trying to accomplish.

Drupal has [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) for this purpose, though:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Clive is right about `field_get_items()` but if for some reason you absolutely want it the way you wrote it, then this will work ( notice the curly braces ) :

```
$json_code = $node->{$field_name}['und'][0]['value']
```

Though you should replace `['und']` with the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE`, e.g. :

```
$json_code = $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
```